# Regex (python) exclude some part of the replacement

Tags: python, regex

For sure there are other ways to solve this, but I'm interested if this can be solved exclusively via regex. I have lines of text like this:

```
9,A
11,B
22,>
33,B
72,A
91,<
112,A
162,B
```

When I try to apply this replacement to basically "join" or erase the part between arrows and replace them with "+++":

```
re.sub(r'\>(\n\d.+)+<','+++',string_above)
```

I get this, which is fine:

```
9,A
11,B
22,+++
112,A
162,B
```

But what if want to keep that last number before the "<" sign and "X" last say, so to get something like this:

```
9,A
11,B
22,+++
91,X
112,A
162,B
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Replace with `r'+++\1X'`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/VlCeEX/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you very much! That was unexpectedly simple. I's the first time I read about the concept of back-referencing, I think it's not mentioned often in introductions to regex unfortunately, but it could be super useful. Is this a language specific feature?

Comment: Almost every language where regex based replacement is implemented supports backreferences in the replacement patterns.

Answer (score 0):

In this concrete case, you may replace with

```
r'+++\1X'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VlCeEX/2)

If `X` is a digit, replace with

```
r'+++\g<1>X'
```

The `\1` and `\g<1>` are called [replacement backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html), these refer to the capturing group #1 value.